# CakePHP code coverage with PHPUnit

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I've been using CakePHP for a while now and recently started using PHPUnit for testing. I'm getting the hang of it and making progress. One thing I'm having trouble with is the code coverage report.

When I test my models I need to instantiate the class and do my tests. That part gets covered in the reports. However, when doing controller tests using tests that extend `AppControllerTest` the report doesn't know what's been tested as it's doing an HTTP request.

Is there any way to have those tests covered in the code coverage report?

Comment: Controller tests shouldn't do HTTP requests, they should be based on CakePHPs integration test case, which simulates requests.

Comment: That's what I meant. I guess they're simulating the HTTP requests. But still the question remains, can these tests show on the code coverage report?

Comment: They can, should, and normally do.

Comment: I have a simple test that extends `IntegrationTestCase` to test the login function. The test runs and passes, and I can make it fail, so I know PHPUnit is running it. But my code coverage still reports nothing. 
I did find one problem I thought might do it, but nope. I had accidentally named my test class `ArticlesControllerTest` instead of `EmployeesControllerTest` but even after renaming it I don't see any change.

Comment: There's not much I can say wihout seeing the involved data. As long as the requests are done properly, and your PHPUnit whitelist configuration includes the files, it should work.